# How to delete empty lists and dictionaries in json row and count them?

Tags: json, python-3.x

How to delete empty lists and dictionaries in json row and count them, for example:

```
[ [ { }, [ ], " ", { {"1":{}, "2":[ ] }, [ [ { } ] , " " ] ] ]
```

Comment: Can you demonstrate *any* effort at solving this yourself?

Comment: I dont know where to start with sequence dictionaries/ one in another to check.

Comment: You're example isn't valid Python; even if it were, what would you want the result to be?

Comment: I want to count how many empty dictionaries and lists can be deleted from row. If it is                                                                                                       [ [ ], [ ] , [ ], ..., [ ] ]  -  I understand.                                                           But how to count something like                                                                                          
[ [ [ { }, [ [ [ { } , "1" ], [ { } ] ] ], " "] ?

Comment: I wrote that I want to delete dictionaries and lists and count how many in question.

Comment: So you should be able to say how many are in your example, and what you expect after the removals are done, and more importantly, *why*.

Comment: A program that removes values from the JSON structure that are empty dictionaries ({}) or empty lists ([]), as long as there are such values. If the value in the dictionary is deleted, the corresponding key is also deleted. You need to count the number of deleted dictionaries and sheets.
Example - [ [ [ [ { } ] ] ] , { }, " "]
The result is 2 3 / 2 dictionaries and 3 lists;
" " is not empty;
[ [ [ ] ] ] - 0 3 (dictionaries, sheets);
[ [ { } ] , { },{ }, " "] - 3 1;
[ " ", { }, {" " :" "}] - 1 0.

Answer (score 0):

This uses an object to handle the recognition & counting of empty things:

```
class Counts:
    d = 0
    l = 0
    def count(self,x):
        if x==[]:
            self.l += 1 
            return True
        elif x=={}:
            self.d += 1
            return True
        return False
    def __repr__(self):
        return "<d=%d, l=%d>" % (self.d,self.l)

def tr(x):
    c = Counts()
    new_x = tr2(x,c)
    c.count(new_x) # Count final result
    return new_x,c.d,c.l 

def tr2(x,c):
    if isinstance(x,dict):
        new_x = {}
        for k,v in x.items():
            if not c.count(v):
                new_v = tr2(v,c)
                if not c.count(new_v):
                    new_x[k] = new_v
        return new_x
    elif isinstance(x,list):
        new_x = []
        for v in x:
            if not c.count(v):
                new_v = tr2(v,c)
                if not c.count(new_v):
                    new_x.append( new_v )
        return new_x
    return x
```